# How to use a word table as mailmerge datasource

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a word document containing a table I need to use as mailmerge datasouce.
I've reached my goal by copying data of the word table to excel and using the sheet as datasource.

Now my question is: is there a way to use the word table as datasource (I mean create a datasource using the data in the word table) without calling excel?

I'm asking this because I need to use a word-vba macro and I'm trying to avoid opening an excel instance.

**edit**

I'll try to clarify what I'm looking for with the following **pseudocode** (I added a "What for this?" in wrong code lines):

```
Dim mDoc As Document
Dim mTbl As Table
Set mDoc = ActiveDocument
Set mTbl = mDoc.Tables(1)

Dim mDS As MailMerge.DataSource 'What for this?

For C = 1 To mTbl.Columns.Count
    'Add Fields
    Dim FieldName As String
    FieldName = mTbl.Cell(1, C).Range.Text
    mDS.Fields.Add (FieldName) 'What for this?
    'Add Values
    For R = 2 To mTbl.Rows.Count
        mDS.Fields(FieldName)(R) = mTbl.Cell(R, C).Range.Text 'What for this?
    Next R
Next C
```

Comment: This is an end-user question, whether you intend to use this in VBA or not. Yes, certainly it's possible to use a Word document as a data source. Just try it in the UI, then record a macro. But the table must be in its own document - the document shouldn't contain anything else.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've already tryed recording a macro but if I record while creating and modifying a datasource nothing is recorded. Anyway I've updated my question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: What you're trying to do is still unclear - perhaps because of the different ways we perceive Word... As a user, go into the Mailings tab. Click "Select Recipients", then "Use existing list". From the dialog box select the file containing the Word table (and only a Word table, no other content). The columns in that table should appear as "fields" for the mail merge, same as when the data is coming from an Excel worksheet. Does that work for you? If yes but it's not exactly what you need: what do you need to have differently that you're trying to achieve using code?

Comment: @CindyMeister You wrote "the file containing the Word table (and only a Word table, no other content)." and here is my goal: I want to use the table I have in the current file but the file may also contains some text. As I wrote I've resolved by saving table in excel but I'm looking for a code who starts a mailmerge without calling an external datasorce but building one by code. Hope I was clear, if not, say me.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, completely, but... Word cannot link to a "virtual" data source. The data source for a mail merge *must* be saved to a file. The only other option is to generate the documents completely from code, without using mail merge.

Answer (score 2):

In Word, start with a blank document, then add one table. Enter the category in the top row (i.e. First Name, Last Name, etc). Then add the data in the rows below. Then you should be able to use a statement like this to connect:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="Y:\Test\Word\MailmergeSource.docx", LinkToSource:=True, SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I'm asking something else.  I'm trying to set a new datasource without external file and add to it fields and values by code using table contento.

Comment: «I'm trying to set a new datasource without external file» Not possible.

Comment: Please don't move the goalposts. Your initial question was how to avoid opening an Excel instance, not how to avoid opening another file. I've answered your original question and would appreciate an upvote.